# Pause parent script until childrens scripts are running

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hope you're doing a great day,

is there any way to pause the parent script until all children scripts end?

I'm doing a script to compress file in different servers and I want to print a message that all logs were compressed:

example:

parent.sh
for server in box1 box2 box2
do
ssh $server compress
done

#### Pause script until all child scripts end

#### after them end show the following

echo "All files were compressed"

---

compress.sh
cd $path
for file in $(ls $path)
do
gzip $file
done

Answer (score 0):

Tnks I solve it by running the child script in background and then into a while I grep the script in jobs and if the count is 0 the script continues.

Answer (score 0):

use "**wait**" bash command.
It will wait until all children processes will be finished.

```
sleep 5 &
sleep 7 &
wait
echo "All sleeps were completed"
```